# How to pass multiple variables on submit?

Tags: php, html, http, post, get

I have a little form:

```
//GET the unit and community id
$UNIT = $_GET['unit'];
$COMID = $_GET['comid'];

...//i have echoed $UNIT and $COMID to ensure that they do have values
...

<form action="ModifyNoteScript.php" method="post"  />
        <input name="Comment" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Comment; ?>" />
        <input name="UNIT" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $UNIT; ?>" />
        <input name="COMID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $COMID; ?>" />
        <textarea name="Comment" cols="55" rows="6" class="text1" id="Comment"><?php echo $Comment; ?>
        </textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="sendnotify" class="formbutton" id="Submit" value="Replace previous note with current" />
      </form>
```

this is it:

[image]

as you can see I am setting the variable `comment` in the `textarea`

it passes over to the next page ModifyNoteScript.php without a problem.

however, the other two variables `UNIT` and `COMID` for some reason get passed as `[blanks]`

here's what ModifyNoteScript.php looks like:

```
<?php
include '../Check.php';
include '../CustomConnect.php';

$UNIT= $_POST['unit']; 
$COMID= $_POST['comid']; 
$NOTE= $_POST['Comment']; 


    $comment_update = mssql_query("UPDATE pmp_property__unit
    SET  
    comments = '$NOTE'
    WHERE 
    communityidy='$COMID' and
    unit='$UNIT'") 
             or die ("Changes to Record could not be Saved."); 




?>
```

**why are those two variables passed over as blanks?**

Comment: What's with the self closing form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your script is opened to XSS attacks because you are not doing any validation (at least that's how it appears).

```
$UNIT = $_GET['unit']; // should be $_POST['UNIT']
$COMID = $_GET['comid']; // should be $_POST['COMID']
```

You are trying to get two GET variables while they are submitted with POST and are uppercase.
Remember that GET and POST variables are case sensitive.

Also you have an `input[type=hidden]` and a `textarea` with the same `name` and they are both submitted. You should change one of them in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks so much, can you give me an example of how i would do validation in order to ensure i dont get attacked?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов, it all comes down to what you expect the GET variable to be. If you are expecting an int you should do `$var = (int) $_GET['key'];` and you should be fine. If you are expecting a string then you should define what characters the string should contain by using REGEX and `preg_match`.

Comment: combination of letters and numbers and dashes

Answer (score 1):

In `ModifyNoteScript.php`, the `$_POST` variables must be:

```
$UNIT= $_POST['UNIT']; // uppercase
$COMID= $_POST['COMID']; // uppercase
$NOTE= $_POST['Comment'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the case differences between your `name` tags and `$_POST` indexes.

You can always try a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're getting.